# Printing pages in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to print pages start with number 1 until number I determine in the file for example I will write in the cell 7 then I need to print first page with number 1 next 2 then 3 until 7 and stop the process the code should be in VBA
Thanks

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Also, you should show what you have tried. You might find looking on here will give you a start. Or you could use the macro record function and edit that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim LastPage As Integer
    
    LastPage = Range("A1").Value
    
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=LastPage, Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
End Sub
```